# Virtual Server or Not?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have been in an argument with a very stubborn guy for a long time about whether his server is virtual or dedicated. He uses his Root server for gameservers, the servers have problems with lag. 
I tell him that this is because the server is operating on virtual CPUs, but he just won't listen.

As I understand it, the server is virtual, and the 'Root' part refers to the use of hosting various websites on it, hence the word 'root'.

Is this server a dedicated server or a virtual server?

http://www.hetzner.de/hosting/produktmatrix/rootserver-produktmatrix-ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu shows it is the EX range is dedicated

[image]

There own [website's meta data also shows this](http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produktmatrix/rootserver):

> meta name="description" content="Unbeatable Web Hosting Offers: Whether Web space, dedicated root server, managed server, vServer or colocation server."

Here, they class a vServer as a different thing meaning it's most likely dedicated.

The feature list http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_rootserver/ex40 also suggests dedicated.

Also, reading about http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/virtualization/virtualization-technology/hardware-assist-virtualization-technology.html shows it's most likely dedicated as well...

And lastly, the price suggests it's dedicated.

Comment: If this is the case, then what can cause the sub-performance of the CPU. Gameservers need good CPU performance, however the servers on here perform worse than a single-core VPS (I tested this myself). There are only 10 gameservers running on it.

Comment: Whilst that is a good question, you're better marking an answer (if applicable) and asking a new question and providing as much as detail as possible - I think every one here feels the same, but if you really want to know, you will have to ask the company direct

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing this anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the link you posted it is a dedicated server (hardware). The most tell-tale sign is that it supports Intel's VT extensions, which is a hardware extension to optimize virtualization. These extensions cannot be virtualized into a guest container/OS.

Also the fact that you can get optional extra's like RAID controllers and disks indicate that he is renting dedicated hardware.

Comment: Containers themselves do not use virtualization, so it's still possible (though _very unlikely_) for VT-x to be exposed to a container...

Answer (score 1):

The page does not make any mention of virtual machine specifications such as vCPUs or partitioned disk space, and in addition it offers "Wake on LAN" which is a function of a physical server, not a virtual server.  I would say it's a physical machine.

Comment: If this is the case, then what can cause the sub-performance of the CPU. Gameservers need good CPU performance, however the servers on here perform worse than a single-core VPS (I tested this myself). There are only 10 gameservers running on it.